# How to create recurring, different rectangles in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.2, flappy-bird-clone

As a beginner at Pygame, and a relative beginner at Python (around 4 months of knowledge), I thought it would be good practice to try and recreate the popular phone app 'Flappy Bird.' I have been fine with doing this, up to the point I am at now. How do I keep one rectangle scrolling, while drawing another that will scroll using the same function? Is this possible? There is probably a method for just this, but I've only been learning the module for less than 7 hours :D Here's my code so far in Python 3.2. (Not including imports)

```
def drawPipe():
    randh = random.randint(40,270)
    scrollx -=0.2
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,150,30), Rect((scrollx,0),(30,340)))


bif = "BG.jpg"
mif = "bird.png"

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,900),0,32)

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
bird = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird")
pygame.display.set_icon(bird)

x,y = 320,0
movex, movey = 0,0

scrollx = 640

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        movey = +0.8
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                movey = -2


    x += movex
    y += movey


    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
    screen.blit(bird,(x,y))

    drawPipe()


    pygame.display.update()
```

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the game. Could you elaborate on the scrolling that you are trying to do?

Comment: Essentially, it is a green, Mario style, pipe (rectangle in my case) that scrolls at different heights endlessly. Originally, I thought,'well it's just scrolling lines. How hard could it be?' But I think having more than one rectangle on the screen at the same time, at a different height is what's posing a problem for me. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first create object that you want to have in the game, with one operation being to draw them.

So instead of having a function that draws a pipe and scrolls, you want to have something along these lines:

```
class Pipe:

def __init__(self,x,height):
    self.rect = Rect((x,0),(30,height))

def update():
    self.rect.move_ip(-2,0)

def draw(screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,self.rect)
```

And then later in game you can have:

```
pipes = [Pipe(x*20,random.randint(40,270)) for x in range(5)]

for pipe in pipes:
    pipe.draw(screen)
    pipe.update()
```

Later on you could just remove the pipes that are not on the screen, and append new ones when a pipe is removed.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to avoid using classes, but I guess it was inevitable. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Harvey There is no shame in using classes. You could just store the Rects themselves in the list, but it is more readable to have separate classes with dedicated methods.

Comment: Well really it's come at a good time because the example you've given me actually has made it click, and I understand classes more now!